# How do I script a change to the msmq storage location on Windows 2008 R2 server

Tags: powershell, batch-file, msmq

Is there any way of doing this through a batch or powershell script? I'm looking for a way to set up several new servers.

The only thing I found on the subject leads me to believe you cannot: from :http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785060.aspx

> The message store location must only be modified using the Storage
>   tab, in Computer Management, Services and Applications, Message
>   Queuing properties.

Edit - I also found this article. It lists some registry values, but again advises against it
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2009/02/09/changing-the-msmq-storage-location.aspx

Comment: Microsoft claims that PowerShell can do everything the UI can. Whether or not that's true in this instance is probably a coin flip.

Comment: Mess with `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters` - restart msmq service - profit!!!

Comment: In the comments to my blog post you're referencing, there's the following from Randy Ridgely: "Starting with Windows 8, there is a PowerShell cmdlet that supports this: Set-MsmqQueueManager. There are options to change the MsgStore, LogMsgStore and TransactionLogStore. You can use get-help Set-MsmqQueueManager -detailed at a PowerShell prompt for more information."

Answer (score 2):

Source: http://www.erbrech.com/blog/2016/05/29/Move-msmq-storage-location-with-powershell-and-Desired-State-Configuration.html

```
$Location = 'E:\msmq\storage'

If(!(test-path $Location))
{
     New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $Location
}

takeown /F $Location /R /D y #this should give me ownership of both msmq and LQS folder
icacls $Location /reset /T /C
icacls $Location "/grant:r" "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService:(OI)(CI)(M)" /T /C
$ConfirmPreference = 'None'

Set-MsmqQueueManager -MsgStore $Location -TransactionLogStore $Location -MsgLogStore $Location

Start-Service MSMQ
```